# Read from complex return types using bun:ffi

Tags: typescript, rust, ffi, bun

I am playing around with the ffi feature and wanted to extend on the documented add example so that it returns complex types (like structs).

This is my rust code:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct SimResult {
    add: isize,
    subtract: isize,
    divide: f64,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn complex(left: isize, right: isize) -> *mut SimResult {
   
    return unsafe {
        transmute(Box::new(SimResult {
            divide: left as f64 / right as f64,
            add: left + right,
            subtract: left - right
        }))
    };
}
```

My TS code looks like this:

```
const lib = dlopen(path, {
  complex: {
    args: [FFIType.i32, FFIType.i32],
    returns: FFIType.ptr,
  }
})

const pointer = pokerClient.symbols.complex()
```

I am getting the pointer, but I am unsure on how to read the data from the pointer. I am fairly new to this territory, so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `transmute` really is **not** necessary here, a simple (and safe) [`Box::into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw) fully suffices.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, only a [few primitive types](https://bun.sh/docs/api/ffi#ffi-types) are supported at the moment.

You can of course provide getters/setters for the properties you're interested in:

```typescript
const lib = dlopen(path, {
    //…
    complex_get_add: {
        args: [FFIType.ptr],
        returns: FFIType.i32,
    }
    complex_set_add: {
        args: [FFIType.ptr, FFIType.i32],
        returns: FFIType.void,
    }
})
```

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn complex_get_add(this: *mut std::ffi::c_void) -> i32 {
    unsafe { (*this.cast::<SimResult>()).add }
        .try_into()
        .unwrap()
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn complex_set_add(this: *mut std::ffi::c_void, add: i32) {
    unsafe { (*this.cast::<SimResult>()).add = add.try_into().unwrap() }
}
//…
```

---

Actually there is a way to read from the pointer in bun directly, [`read` and `DataView`](https://bun.sh/docs/api/ffi#pointers) but both require manual specification of the offsets into the struct and the type of the field, I wouldn't personally go that route but one could definitely write a nice abstraction which reads the Rust/C definition of the struct around that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I ended up using serde for now to serialize the return types to a json string